# How to make upside down in MS Excel 2007?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

How to make data upside down with a single click in MS Excel 2007 like shown in the below picture?

[image]

after making upside down

[image]

As well how to reverse it back with a single click?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Excel can do this on its own, but I found this macro

```
Sub FlipRows()
    Dim vTop As Variant
    Dim vEnd As Variant
    Dim iStart As Integer
    Dim iEnd As Integer
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        iStart = 1
        iEnd = Selection.Rows.Count
        Do While iStart < iEnd
            vTop = Selection.Rows(iStart)
            vEnd = Selection.Rows(iEnd)
            Selection.Rows(iEnd) = vTop
            Selection.Rows(iStart) = vEnd
            iStart = iStart + 1
            iEnd = iEnd - 1
        Loop
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

here

http://excel.tips.net/T002653_Flipping_Data.html

Comment: Note that the entire table needs to be selected before running this macro.

Answer (score 1):

`If you do want to do it with "clicks" only, then you need VBA, and this question is better asked on Stack Overflow`

You can do this with an array formula (ie without VBA)

See Pearson's [Reversing The Order Of A List](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/lists.htm)

If your data was in A1:C3 then

- Select E1:G3
- put this formula in the formula bar `=OFFSET(A$1:A$3,MAX(ROW($D$1:$D$3))-ROW(),0)`
- hit Shift  Ctrl & Enter together to enter this as an *array* formula

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding numbering to a column to the right of the data, like this:

```
Raju  100   34   1
Ravi  234   45   2
kavi  232   32   3
```

Select the data, then do a descending sort by the 4th column.

Then feel free to delete the fourth column.